# Magento 2 Argument 1 passed getProductFromLocalCache() must be of the type string, null given, called

Tags: magento2, migration, data-migration

After migration Magento 1 to 2.3.4, I have facing an error on some product edit.

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getProductFromLocalCache()
>   must be of the type string, null given, called in
>   /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php
>   on line 270

Can you please help me to resolve this error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For affected product has no SKU. Add SKU for that product this error will be fixed.
You can update directly from MySQL, the table name is: **catalog_product_entity**

Answer (score 6):

There is some blank SKU save into admin section so you need to change status for that.

```
UPDATE **prefix_**catalog_product_entity SET sku='' WHERE sku IS NULL;
```

Just run above query using you prefix if you have than check you admin section working properly.